# Google one-tap sign-in/sign-up, Access personal Data

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-identity, google-smartlockpasswords

I just started using google on-tap sing-in/sign-up in my new app.
It works perfectly except that I don't know how can I ask user permissions to access scoped data?

```
client.verifyIdToken(
    token,
    CLIENT_ID,
    function(e, login) {
      var payload = login.getPayload(); // <-- payload just containt name,email and picture. I want more
      var userid = payload['sub']; 
    });
```

Comment: FirebaseUI-web offers a full authentication system with integration with one-tap sign-up. It also provides support for additional Google OAuth scopes via one-tap click: https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/#one-tap-sign-up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Google Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web) to authorize more scopes. Pass the email address of the account returned by One-Tap as the `login_hint` parameter to the [`gapi.auth2.init`](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#gapiauth2initparams) call, then call `gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn()` so that the user can grant access to the other scopes your app require.

You can also use [`gapi.auth2.authorize`](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#gapiauth2authorizeparams-callback) for One-Off authorization (if you use `gapi.client` to perform requests to Google APIs, you generally want to use `init/signIn`).

Comment: The only issue I'm having with your suggestion is that the prompt still appears and closes itself even though I have set `prompt:none` and `login_hint:'some@gmail.com'` as options for `gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn(option)`. Very annoying.

Comment: You cannot use `prompt: 'none'` in the `signIn` call. Only `gapi.auth2.authorize` takes this parameter.